# New SSD freezing on older motherboard (intel G31)

Tags: windows-7, ssd, motherboard, freeze, hdtv

I have an ECS G31T-M motherboard running a Core2 Quad processor, 4gb RAM, Windows 7 32bit, Geforce 9600GT.  Bought a Sandisk Extreme III 120GB (SDSSDX-120G-G25) and installed today.  I'm outputting this from my 9600GT with included TV-out adapter to Component video (to my HDTV).

This motherboard is SATA 2 and from what I can tell, SSDs run on the IDE controller and there is nothing fancy to set up advanced features of SSDs.  I've noticed on other forums (but not verifying with ECS) this board does not support AHCI.

I have two versions of Windows 7 installed on two drives, the SSD and an old 500G disc drive.  When booted from my older 500G HDD, video plays fine on the HDTV.  When booting the SSD windows 7 install, I am freezing constantly, as in, video plays OK for a minute, then picture freezes for 1-3 minutes (sometimes as audio continues playing) and returns for 20-30 seconds before doing the same thing again.  Other tasks such as basic maneuvering through file folders seems to be no problem.

Please help!!  Do I need a new system for this thing to work, or could there be other fixes?  I updated firmware to R201 to no avail.

DJM

Comment: Is it possible that your SSD might be saturating the IDE controller?

Comment: @RandolphWest: If true, that would be great. That would mean his SSD was giving him the maximum performance the controller was capable of.

Comment: Other thoughts?  I do have another 180GB IDE hard drive attached to the controller, but that should not matter, right?  Is having a newer motherboard going to make all the difference?  I still thought that I'd see some gains over a disc HDD but the freezing is obviously not welcome.